# Pdftron Sdk throwing error in azure web app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, pdftron

My problem is when I am adding a PdfTron Sdk to web solution manually and deploying the solution to Web app service in azure cloud. I am getting the below error.

Stack trace error message in azure files.

Comment: Hi @madhu babu, please update your post to add your error information.

Answer (score 0):

The standard/native Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine. It appears to be due to Sandbox restriction, as Peter mentioned please share do share more details on the error. 
For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked. One common pattern that is affected is PDF file generation. 
Kindly review this document [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) - supported/Unsupported frameworks.

Additionally, just to highlight based on your requirement you could leverage container based App Service. 
Checkout these documents for more details on this topic:

[Run a custom Linux container in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker)

[Run a custom Windows container in Azure (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container)